# How to import script (.sql extension) database into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, sql-server-2012-express

I have a problem in importing a database script in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio however, I successfully exported the schema and data. In exporting the database, I have done the steps:

1. Right click on the database under Tasks;
2. Click generate scripts and follow the wizard;
3. Advance option: Types of data to script = Schema and data
4. Finished

However, when I open the file and transfer it in an empty database (execute the `script.sql`) using SQL Server Management Studio, I can't import it. On SQL Server 2008 I can easily do that thing but on SQL Server 2012, I think there is something wrong on it.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

And when I try to execute the script.sql file on the new Copy of database (db_Copy), There is an error message below. ''

[image]

Please help me on this issue, Have I done something wrong in exporting my data (Generate script)? Or It can be on SQL Server I'm using? I am using SQL Server 2012 Express.

Please help me, All i want to do is to my database to another database using the generated scripts.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: What is the proper way to import the generated scripts on the empty database?

Comment: What about the error isn't clear to you? That database `db_Dasureco` you're trying to create in the SQL script already exists on this SQL Server instance. Either don't try to create it again, or use a different database name ......

Comment: Yes. I tried to change the database name, ex. CREATE DATABASE [db_NewCopyDatabase] , but it didn't execute. I executed the script then it takes 10 mins now of running the script. Is it normal?

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty database or if you have one already target that one.

Open CMD with elevated privilege and run:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -d MYDATABASE -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -i C:\path\mysqlfile.sql -o C:\path\results.txt
```

basically:

- **-S:** is your servername or localhost
- **-d:** is the database you are targeting
- **-U:** is the username
- **-P:** is the password
- **-i:** is the path to your .sql file
- **-o:** is where the logs file will be saved so if you had problem during the importation you can debug them

Answer (score 0):

Replace [db_Dasureco] for [db_NewCopyDatabase] not only in CREATE DATABASE, but everywhere you see [db_Dasureco].